# How to handle users who gives multiple answers for the same post

Tags: support

This [User](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/21649) gave two answers for this [Question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/109503/log-out-issues-in-drupal-7), instead of edit her first answer. How to handle this post.

Can I edit their post, to merge those two answers into a single? or do I need to give down vote for one of the answer and left comment is sufficient?

Comment: If answers are different, why not? Different solutions should be voted separately, even if one person posted them both.

Comment: @Mołot  - Oh! really!! thanks Molot. I thought that, user should provide both answers in single post.
Ok if second answer is also related to first answer from same user, then how to handle?

Comment: Comment. If user don't explain / fix it, flag for moderator's attention.

Comment: @Mołot - Great!! now it's clear to me. Thanks!

Comment: @Bala - Yes bala, I didn't notice that. I'm going to delete this post

Comment: you can't because you have 1 answer post and I close the question for duplicate.

Comment: @Bala - Yes,I've just flag this question to close ;) :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Giving two answers is perfectly acceptable, especially if the answers are giving two solutions that are completely different from each other. In this case, giving two answers makes more easy for other users to vote: The users who find one of the answers completely wrong, but good the other one, will down-vote one of the questions, and up-vote the other one.

In the specific, an answer is merely a link, and the other one is an answer specific for a browser. The first one should be expanded to include the necessary bits of information; the other one doesn't seem much pertinent, since it is suggesting what to do on the browser side, but that doesn't seem the problem, or the same issue would happen with the admin account.